# Не удаётся использовать Mockito.spy в junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Пытаюсь понять как пользоваться Mockito и никак не получается использовать Mockito.spy.

Вот такой вот код (просто как образец):

```
@Test
public void testTest(){
    Player.Point newPoint = new Player.Point(4, 5);
    Player.Point spyPoint = spy(newPoint);

    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    when(spyPoint.isDistShot(x, y)).thenReturn(false);
    Assert.assertFalse(spyPoint.isDistShot(x, y));
}
```

junit (кажется это он) ругается вот такими словами и крашится:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2 (file:/C:/Users/Ocean/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-all/1.10.19/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$2 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Не могу понять, тест ругается на рефлексию, при этом если использовать не `spy`, а `mock` - то всё нормально.
Но с моком я не знаю как создать объект класса с параметрами в конструкторе.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно использовать `spy` в тестировании?

Answer (score 0):

#### Решение

Замените

```java
when(spyPoint.isDistShot(x, y)).thenReturn(false);
```

на

```java
doReturn(false).when(spyPoint).isDistShot(x, y);
```

#### Пояснение

`spy` использует реальный объект, поэтому когда вы вызываете `spyPoint.isDistShot(x, y)`, моки еще не настроены и происходит вызов метода оригинального объекта.

---

**P.S.**
Вы предоставили информацию о предупреждении, которое никак не связано с описанной проблемой.
Стектрейс реального исключения остался загадкой.